# scanset not working properly in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

hello i am  new to visual studio code and i searched regarding how to read string with space in c

and got the following methods

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-string-input-space-c-3-different-methods/

so i used the scanset specifed in the above link in visual studio it was working fine for one program

to say specifically if only one scanf with scanset is present that too at first it works

following are the two programs where in first one scanset not reading any thing , so i checked in other  program where scanset worked fine

here  are two programs

1)where scanset not even reading a string and exits

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    char s[1000];
    int N,K,T = 0;
    int g=0;

    scanf("%d",&T);

    scanf("%d%d",&N,&K);

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s);
    
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=N/2;j++){
            if(s[j]!=s[N-j+1]){
                g= g+1;
            }
    }
    if(g!=K){
        printf("Case #%d: %d",T,K-g);
    }
    
    
}

}
```

**output**

```
PS C:\Users\SriHarsha> cd "c:\Users\SriHarsha\" ; if ($?) { g++ kgoodness.cpp -o kgoodness } ; if ($?) { .\kgoodness }
1 
5 2
PS C:\Users\SriHarsha>
```

2. 

where scanset read a string and gave output but when i used other scanf to read simple character the second scanf statement  is not working

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char s[1000];
    char d;
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%c",s[i]);
    }

    scanf("%c",&d);
    printf("%c",d);

}
```

**output**

```
PS C:\Users\SriHarsha> cd "c:\Users\SriHarsha\" ; if ($?) { g++ scanf.cpp -o scanf } ; if ($?) { .\scanf }
sri
sri

PS C:\Users\SriHarsha>
```

Comment: `scanf("%d%d",&N,&K); scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s);` has trouble reading `1(space)2\nXYZ\n"`.  Consider `fgets()` to read all user input.

Comment: Suggest [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537/2410359)

Comment: Are you still using `scanf()` someplace or only `fgets()`?

Comment: Thankyou monica your suggestion worked

Comment: sorry it worked i was giving scanf(" %c  ") instead of scanf(" %c")

Answer (score 0):

In both cases where `scanf` appears to not work, the format specifier for reading a string is malformed..

This format specifier for this `scanf` call is malformed and won't actually read a string into variable `s` `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s);`

If your intent is to read a string into `s`, I'd suggest changing that line to this: `scanf("%s",s);`

Comment: `scanf("%s",s);` will not work for OP's "how to read string with space".  Without a width limit, it is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: Monica its not showing any error value                                                                  `PS C:\Users\SriHarsha> cd "c:\Users\SriHarsha\" ; if ($?) { g++ kgoodness.cpp -o kgoodness } ; if ($?) { .\kgoodness }                                                               

1
 
Value of errno: 0
                                                                                                                                             
 5 2                                                                                              
 Value of errno: 0
  Value of errno: 0`